# IGBT chip metalization

Tags: mosfet, design, semiconductors, igbt, chip-design

Consider an IGBT chip within a power module.

The top surface of the chip is often metalized by aluminum (with approximately 5 microns thickness) to bond some aluminum wires into the chip; I am hazy about the chip bottom-side metalization.

Which material is used to construct the bottom-side metalization and how thick is it?

[image]

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but why wouldn't it be Aluminum just like the top?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit_packaging): "Die attachment is the step during which a die is mounted and fixed to the package or support structure (header).[11] For high-powered applications, the die is usually eutectic bonded onto the package, using e.g. gold-tin or gold-silicon solder (for good heat conduction). For low-cost, low-powered applications, the die is often glued directly onto a substrate (such as a printed wiring board) using an epoxy adhesive."  IGBT's probably fall under the high-power category.